# $3$-manifold has same homology groups as a $3$-sphere.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a compact connected $3$-manifold with boundary $\partial M$. If $M$ is orientable, $\partial M$ is empty, and $H_1(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, does it follow that $M$ has the same homology groups as a $3$-sphere?

Comment: ...any thoughts on this? Do you at least have an idea of what kind of tools you need to use to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Since $M$ is orientable, without boundary and connected, we have $H_0(M;\mathbb{Z}) = H_3(M;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$. Using [Poincaré duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality), you know that the torsion subgroup of $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the torsion subgroup of $H_{3-2-1}(M;\mathbb{Z}) = H_0(M;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$ and thus is zero. Using Poincaré duality again, you know that the free part of $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the free part of $H_{3-2}(M;\mathbb{Z}) = H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and thus $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$. This shows that $M$ has the homology groups of a three dimensional sphere.

Comment: This is needlessly roundabout (cf. Daniel Valenzuela's answer), Poincaré duality and the universal coefficient theorem immediately give the answer -- which is also why I would have wished for the OP to give their thoughts about the question or at least what tool they knew, but that cat's out of the bag now...

Comment: I don't see much difference between my answer and Daniel's. I used a version of Poincaré duality that already includes inside the usage of the universal coefficient theorem instead of using the "regular" version and then applying the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Well no, conceptually there's no difference, I agree. But the exposition is a bit roundabout, that's what I'm saying... The situation is simple enough that the "regular" universal coefficient is clearer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

A closed orientable $n$-manifold is called homology sphere if it has homology (or equivalently cohomology) of a sphere.

Note that for a closed connected orientable 3-manifold we have always $H_0M\cong \mathbb Z \cong H_3M$ and also $H_2M \cong H^1M \cong Hom(H_1M,\mathbb Z)$. You see that $H_1M=0$ forces it to be a homology sphere.